# Xcode can't find one of my gsl headers

Tags: c++, xcode, gsl

I installed gsl in /developer/usr/ and applied these settings:

Header Search Paths: /usr/local/include
Library Search Paths: /usr/local/lib
Other Linker Flags: -lgsl -lm

After that Xcode can find just about every header file in gsl besides gsl_odeiv2.h, including gsl_odeiv.h. Any idea why this one header can't be found?

Comment: Have you tried adding /developer/usr/local/include to the search path and /developer/usr/local/lib?

Comment: Is gsl_odeiv2.h really there?

Comment: gsl_odeiv2.h is there and I did try adding /developer, but it didn't help.